# STA 3033 - Tchebysheff’s theorem

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, education, order-statistics

I'm learning how to apply the theorem and I saw the example below and I'm not sure if that person got it wrong or it's just like that:

The time that takes to complete a certain type of construction projects has a mean of 35.5 months and a standard deviation of 1.5 months.

a. According to the Tchebysheff’s theorem, at least what percentage of these projects must have taken between 26.5 months and 44.5 months to complete?

He did this:

1 - 1/k^2 = 1 - 1/6^2 = 0.972222222 = 97.22222%

If in addition we are told that the relative frequency curve for the completion times is a bell- shaped curve, then approximately what percentage of these projects would take more than 34 months to completed

We first get the **z score** for the critical value. As z = (x - u) sqrt(n) / s, then as

x = critical value =    34

u = mean =    35.5

s = standard deviation =    1.5

z = (x - u) / s =    -1

Thus, using a table/technology, the right tailed area of this is

P(z >   -1   ) =    0.841344746 = **84.13%**

Can someone exaplin me how he did from the z-score below please? and is that even right?

Thank you!

Comment: For the first part, if X were normal, then in R `diff(pnorm(c(26.5, 44..5), 35.5, 1/5))` returns a number very close to 1. Chebyshev's ineq. guarantees prob. at least 0.972, so the computation you have seems reasonable. Do you know where $6$ comes from? // For the second part you are supposed to assume that X is normal and find $P(X > 34).$ In R, this is `1 - pnorm(34, 35.5, 1.5)`, which returns  0.8413447. You will not get this many places of accuracy with printed tables, but again the answer you post looks OK. Also, 34 is 1 $\sigma$ below $\mu,$ so by the Empirical Rule prob is about .84.

Comment: Thanks @BruceET, the test was yesterday but I appreciate your help.

Comment: My guess is that some of these same ideas will pop up again on the next test. So try to understand the Empirical Rule and the use of normal tables for sure.

Comment: That's true. I'll probably use it for the final. Thank you @BruceET